# JProfiler - losing results on JVM OOM

Tags: java, jprofiler

Is it possible to make JProfiler not loose results when JVM exits? I'm trying to profile OOM, and as soon as JVM gets OOM, profiler looses all the data.

Answer (score 0):

The profiling data lives in the profiling agent that runs inside the JVM process. If that process dies, the profiling information is gone. There is no way to save a JProfiler snapshot when an OOME occurs. Things you can do are

1. Pass the

   ```
   -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
   ```

   VM parameter to the JVM in order to capture a HPROF heap snapshot exactly when the OOME occurs. You can open HPROF snapshots in JProfiler.
2. Add a "Heap usage threshold trigger" in JProfiler and set the threshold to something like 90%. A JProfiler snapshot will be saved at that threshold which should allow you to analyze a memory leak.

Comment: I always thought that remote profiling agent is sending data at some intervals, and that data is cached locally - for example history of memory usage, cpu usage etc. It is really frustrating to have it completely gone from the GUI. I think it would be better just to have notification that connection is lost, but to be able at least to view already filled-in list boxes and graphs that are visible in client.

Comment: Yes, some data like the telemetries are in the UI, but most other data is not. Unfortunately, we cannot support a disconnected state that only shows the data that is already available.